# Remove duplicates checking more than one rows dataframe

Tags: r

Having a dataframe:

```
dframe <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3,2,2), name = c("Google","Google","Google","Amazon","Google"))
```

How is it possible to check both columns in the same time and remove duplicates

Example output

```
data.frame(id = c(1,3,2,2), name = c("Google","Google","Amazon","Google"))
```

What I tried

```
dframe[!duplicated(dframe ["id", "name"]), ]
```

Comment: Try `dframe %>% distinct()`

Comment: Try `duplicated(dframe)`. More exactly, `dframe[!duplicated(dframe), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

The `distinct` function from `dplyr` might be what you are looking for:

```
dframe %>%
    distinct(id, name)

  id   name
1  1 Google
2  2 Google
3  3 Google
4  2 Amazon
```

Comment: if the dataframe has more than these two columns and I want to check them it doesn't work

Comment: So you would want to specify all columns inside `distinct` that are relevant for you definition of duplicates. If this includes all columns, you can just write `distinct()`

Comment: No it is just you saw but in my real dataset it keep only the column which are inside the distinct. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Ah you want to set `.keep_all = TRUE` then to keep other columns

Comment: distinct(id, name, .keep_all = TRUE) is this form?